# Exporting randomly generated strings from Terraform

Tags: chef-infra, terraform

**Context:**

I am running a 2-stage deployment

1. Create an EC2 instance and RDS instance using terraform
2. Configure the EC2 instance using chef

**Problem:**

Say that I use Terraform to create an RDS instance in AWS, something like this:

```
resource "random_string" "rds_password" {
  length = 16
  special = true
}

resource "aws_db_instance" "rds" {
  allocated_storage    = 20
  storage_type         = "gp2"
  engine               = "postgres"
  engine_version       = "9.3.14"
  instance_class       = "db.t2.micro"
  name                 = "postgres"
  username             = "postgres"
  password             = "${random_string.rds_password.result}"
  db_subnet_group_name = "${var.subnet.["rds_subnet_group"]}"
  parameter_group_name = "default.postgres9.3"
  identifier           = "${var.rds.["rds_name"]}"
  skip_final_snapshot  = true
  publicly_accessible  = true
}
```

How would I:

- Randomly generate the password string (i.e. is the method used above
  appropriate)
- "Pass" that password string to a db.properties file on the EC2 instance in a secure way (currently I manage the db.properties file as a template in a chef cookbook)
- Be given an output of the password in plain text (for manual db
  troubleshooting and configuration).

Answer (score 0):

The naive option would be to use the `attributes_json` parameter on the Chef provisioner inside Terraform. That would result in the password being stored in the clear in some unfortunate places though so probably better to instead store it in something like SSM Paramstore or S3 and then have Chef use the instance's IAM credentials to retrieve it. Also remember you probably don't want to give the instance the root account/password, you want to make a user for the app with reduced permissions.

Comment: Storing the password in S3 is an interesting thought - So you are suggesting that I use Terraform's aws_s3_bucket_object resource to generate a random, plain text password directly to an encrypted S3 bucket?

Comment: No, you generate it the same way, and then write it to an S3 object.